# React/Nextjs context provider state not accessible on first load / refresh, but works fine when state changes

Tags: react-hooks, next.js, react-context

I am learning react and I am at where I am building state management using context api. My context is like this:

```
//TodoContext.js
const todos = [];
const totalTodos = () => {};
const getTodos = () => {};
const saveTodos = () => {};
export const TodoContext = createContext({todos, totalTodos, getTodos, saveTodos })
```

And through a custom hook I do this.

```
//useTodos.js
export default function useTodos(){
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]); //added in an attempt to trigger change on value update
  const totalTodos = () => {
     return todos.length;
  }
  const getTodos = () => {
    let todoList = [];
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        todoList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
    }
    return todoList;
  }
  const saveTodos = (todos) => {
   //saves to local storage, then:
   setTodos(todos)
  }
 return { todos, totalTodos, getTodos, saveTodos  }
}
```

And in my layout file:

```
const { todos, totalTodos, getTodos } = useTodos();
...
return (
   <TodosContext.Provider value={ todos, totalTodos, getTodos, saveTodos }>
     <div>Todo count: {totalTodos()}</div>
     {children}
   </TodosContext.Provider>
)
```

My issue is that `{totalTodos}` is not shown when I first load the page or navigate to another page which uses this same layout. But, if a, say for example, save a new todo using the `saveTodos` method, `totalTodos` starts showing the correct value and after that every thing looks to be working fine. What am I doing wrong? I have different ideas like using memo and useRef and the like but I couldn't wrap my head around the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you try `todos.length` instead of `totalTodos` ?

Comment: @ChemiAdel thanks, but same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this using this method (refactored a code to fetch api result found elsewhere):

In the layout file:
const [todosCount, setTodosCount] = useState(0)

```
const getCount = () => {
  setTodosCount( totalTodos() )
  return () => {} 
}
useEffect( ()=>{
  getCount()
})
```

---

Coincidentally looks like this is working as well:

```
useEffect( ()=>{
  setTodosCount( totalTodos() )
}, [()=>{}]); //passing an empty function
```

Needless to say that I have no idea what's happening, but it's working. Will update answer once I find more information on what's happening or explanation from anyone experienced is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `useEffect` to initialize the state once the hook called

**useTodos.js**

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
    
...code    
    
//useEffect helps to update states once when client-side ready (only with [])
useEffect(() => {
    
todoList = localStorage.getItem('todos');
    
setTodos(todoList)
    
},[]); <--- client-side only
```

Comment: I have actually tried this before and this gives the correct value on load but reactivity is lost; as in when I change state the count doesn't get updated.

Comment: try `todos.length` instead of `totalTodos()` with `useEffect`